# Express 4 increase nodejs memory

Tags: node.js, express

How do I increase nodejs memory for express app?
If I am running a single node file I can simply do the following,

```
node --max-old-space-size=1024 my-node-script.js #increase to 1gb
node --max-old-space-size=2048 my-node-script.js #increase to 2gb
node --max-old-space-size=3072 my-node-script.js #increase to 3gb
node --max-old-space-size=4096 my-node-script.js #increase to 4gb
node --max-old-space-size=5120 my-node-script.js #increase to 5gb
node --max-old-space-size=6144 my-node-script.js #increase to 6gb
node --max-old-space-size=7168 my-node-script.js #increase to 7gb
node --max-old-space-size=8192 my-node-script.js #increase to 8gb
```

However now I am running `forever start -c "npm start" ./` for my server so where do I put the `--max-old-space-size=8192` statement?

Comment: in your package.json
"scripts": {
    "start": "node --max-old-space-size=1024 my-node-script.js"}

Comment: Thank you current my script in package.json is `"scripts": {
    "start": "set NODE_ENV=production && node ./bin/www"
  },` so how do I add on to that?

Comment: "scripts": { "start": "set NODE_ENV=production && node  --max-old-space-size=1024./bin/www" }